# Not a valid entity or mapped super class

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have 2 bundles, 1 CMS bundle that will be the parent bundle.
I have in both bundles duplicated entitys. Like `User` The user in the CMS bundle i made it a abstract class. (not sure if that is the right choice. Actually, what I want is extending my user entity IF needed.).

cms user:

```
abstract class User implements UserInterface
```

bundle user:

```
use MV\CMSBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MV\NameBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @DoctrineAssert\UniqueEntity(fields={"email"}, message="user.email.already.exist" )
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    ....
}
```

Im getting the error `Class "MV\CMSBundle\Entity\User" is not a valid entity or mapped super class.`

I have searched in the documentation of symfony and found this page: [entities-entity-mapping](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/bundles/override.html#entities-entity-mapping) but they didn't add some content xD

Oh, and no I dont want to use FOSUserBundle ;)

Symfony: 2.1

Comment: try using \MV\CMSBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser

Comment: Same, should not matters.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Define the base-class as follows:

```
/**
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
 */
abstract class BaseUser
{
    // ...
}
```

Define the real entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    // ...
}
```

Because you're missing the @MappedSuperclass annotation on the base-class, Doctrine throws the exception you mention.

Answer (score 30):

In my case I was missing `* @ORM\Entity` in my class definition.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="listtype")
 */
class ListType
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In my case, the problem was `eaccelerator` because it strips out all the comments which **Doctrine** uses. After disabling `eaccelerator` it worked . You can disable your php settings or,

in the `web/app_dev.php` or `web/app.php` file.

```
<?php
    ini_set('eaccelerator.enable', 0);
    ini_set('eaccelerator.optimizer', 0);
    //rest of the code.
```

**Note:** Do clear the symfony2 cache after disabling this.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. But to make it work but, I had to shift the lines:

```
* @ORM\Table
* @ORM\Entity
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in linux server. Be careful with case sensitive. I had to replace this:

```
/**
 * @entity
 * @table(name="listtype")
 */
class ListType
{
    ...
}
```

With this:

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="listtype")
 */
class ListType
{
    ...
}
```