# How to fix class is not a valid entity or mapped super class?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

So I'm trying to follow [symfony2's tutorial on doctrine](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html) for my own website  and modeling my `User` entity after their `Product` one.

Also, before anyone marks this a duplicate, I have already tried the solutions given in numerous other questions with no luck:

- [Not a valid entity or mapped super class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14662535/not-a-valid-entity-or-mapped-super-class)
- [Doctrine class is not a valid entity or mapped super class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19144603/doctrine-class-is-not-a-valid-entity-or-mapped-super-class)
- [Symfony/Doctrine: Class is not a valid entity or mapped super class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17765591/symfony-doctrine-class-is-not-a-valid-entity-or-mapped-super-class)
- [symfony2 is not a valid entity or mapped super class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14986080/symfony2-is-not-a-valid-entity-or-mapped-super-class)
- [Symfony/Doctrine: Class is not a valid entity or mapped super class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17765591/symfony-doctrine-class-is-not-a-valid-entity-or-mapped-super-class)
- ["Class XXX is not a valid entity or mapped super class" after moving the class in the filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7820597/class-xxx-is-not-a-valid-entity-or-mapped-super-class-after-moving-the-class-i)

and the list goes on

I have my entity class:

```
<?php
    namespace MySite\MyBundle\Entity;

    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

    /**
     * @ORM\Entity
     * @ORM\Table(name="user")
     */
    class User
    {
        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
        protected $id;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
         */
        protected $name;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
         */
        protected $password;
    }
?>
```

Now, I'm running the command:

```
$ php app/console doctrine:generate:entities MySite/MyBundle/Entity/User
```

to generate the accessor methods. However, when I do this, I get the error:

```
[Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]
Class "MySite\MyBundle\Entity\User" is not a valid entity or mapped super class.
```

Comment: When you use php app/console doctrine:generate:entities - it means that you generate entity from database. But you create entity manualy and try to overwrite it. Run **php app/console doctrine:mapping:info**

It will show you if you have problems in the mapping structure in doctrine

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is the symfony tutorial wrong then? In the "Generating Getters and Setters" section, it says "doctrine:generate:entities" is to generate getters and setters. And when I run doctrine:mapping:info I get: [Exception] You do not have any mapped Doctrine ORM entities according to the current configuration. If you have entities or mapping files you should check your mapping configuration for errors.

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html - tutorial

Comment: I'm not trying to generate them from a database, but from the PHP files. Anyways, I figured it out, I was missing a `auto_mapping: true` line in my config.yml; everything works as expected now.

Comment: Good. If user user2443357 gave correct answer, please set answer as "correct"

Comment: I just did, stackoverflow doesn't let you accept your own answer for 3 days

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out myself. My problem is that my config.yml was wrong. I was missing the `auto_mapping: true` line in my config.yml.

```
doctrine:
    # (dbal stuff here)

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        auto_mapping: true
```

After adding that, everything auto-generates fine with the `php app/console doctrine:generate:entities MySite/MyBundle/Entity/User` line

Comment: I am having the exact same issue as you, generating a simple entity from the Symfony2 book and failing. I did check auto_mapping and it didn't work for me. Hmm.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I found at the end the problem in my case was I missed the class that extends Bundle

```
namespace Acme\TagBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class AcmeTagBundle extends Bundle
{
}
```

and declaring that class in AppKernel.php under the bundles array.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I named the folder entity instead of Entity. When I fixed that it worked like a charm.